# What are easy to understand Japanese podcasts?

Tags: discussion

**Preface:**

I originally posted this question on https://japanese.stackexchange.com, but was informed that it is off topic and would be more suitable to this forum. Thus, without further ado:

**Original question:**

I learned English at school up to around B2/C1 level. I continued at university, but not having much time for studying English, my progress slowed down significantly. However, I was able to pick up speed again and improve much more in understanding and vocabulary when I started listening to English podcasts. This was more of fluke than deliberate as I didn't specifically search for these podcasts. I stumbled upon them when searching for my interests on the internet.

Now, I have been learning Japanese at the university for around 5 years and am at around B2/C1 again. I would like to repeat the feat by listening to Japanese podcasts, but I have trouble finding suitable ones. Can anyone recommend podcasts for my level of Japanese?

Wait, before you answer: This being a stackexchange forum, I think it would help my question to be generalized. Thus, what I would like to know is:

- **What podcasts do you recommend?** (Vlogs, and video channels are fine as well, but I would prefer listening to watching.)
- **What is the podcast about?**
- **What language level do I need to understand it?** (I am searching for B2/C1, but other levels might help other Japanese learners.)

Comment: *cough cough* https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70322/what-are-easy-to-understand-japanese-podcasts But, great question, and I hope this question is answered.

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately...